# Problems with signature creation for banklink

Tags: php, openssl

I'm stuck finilizing a banklink, I get response, that my signature is wrong.

This is the signature part manual that the bank sent

> Digital signature MAC is XML data hash value, encrypted with senders private key.
>   For hash value calculations SHA-1 algorithm is used, but for signature calculation RSA algorithm is used. Digital signature transforms to textual format using BASE64 encoding and is placed to MAC field.

And what I have build up:

```
// the key is loaded succesfull
private function setPrivateKey ( $key_name ) {
  $fp = fopen( $this -> getKeyLocation() . '/' . $key_name, "r" );
  $priv_key = fread( $fp, 8192 );
  fclose( $fp );
  $this -> private_key = openssl_get_privatekey( $priv_key );
}

// signature is created, but not the way bank expects it
private function setSignature () {
  // also tried sha1( $data, true );
  // signature contains no special chars ( meaning no UTF8 specific coding )
  $pre_mac = sha1( $this -> getXMLData() );
  openssl_sign( $pre_mac, $signature, $this -> getPrivateKey() );
  $this -> signature = $signature;
}

// can't be a problem here
private function setMac () {
  $this -> mac = base64_encode( $this -> getSignature() );
}

// this is set correctly
private function setXMLData () {
    $bank_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <bl>
    <snd>PHP_COMPANY</snd>
    <query>NEW</query>
    <type>PHP_TYPE</type>
    <data>
        <client_id>A71045</client_id>
        <amount>PHP_AMOUNT</amount>
        <ccy_name>PHP_CURR</ccy_name>
        <ccy_code>1</ccy_code>
        <bnf_name>PHP_COMPANY</bnf_name>
        <bnf_account>PHP_ACCOUNT</bnf_account>
        <bnf_id>PHP_CID</bnf_id>
        <residence_id>LV</residence_id>
        <residence_name>LV-LATVIA</residence_name>
        <details>PHP_DETAILS</details>
    </data>
    <date>PHP_DATE</date>
    <time>PHP_TIME</time>
    <reply>
        <session_id>PHP_SESSION</session_id>
    </reply>
    <reply_url>PHP_REPLY</reply_url>
    </bl>';

    $this -> bank_xml = $bank_xml;
}
```

It seems to me that I'm not encrypting it right. Any suggestions what might be wrong?
I believe I have made every step what the bank requires.

I already sent this to the bank, but they respond w/in a week or so.

PS: get functions are all set that return the set variable, I just didn't think it's necessary to post them.

Comment: What does `$this->getXMLData()` return - a string or an object/array?

Comment: Btw, it's said in openssl_sign [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) that $data get hashed to SHA-1 in process; did you try omitting that intermediate hashing altogether?

Comment: Yup, I started w/out `$pre_mac = sha1( $this -> getXMLData() );` line.

Comment: Had the bank provided some sort of sample data to check your algorithm with?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing that I know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed the problem. It seems that the bank manual is not correct ( still waiting for the answer from bank though ).

Replaced sha1 with md5 and all became valid.

```
$pre_mac = md5( $this -> getXMLData() );
```

Thanx [raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow), you pointed me to the right direction with your coment:

> did you try omitting that intermediate hashing altogether?